# How to cut a curve

Tags: curve-modifier, boolean-modifier

I would like to cut this this circle and it is a curve so I do not have access to the boolean, how to (open it)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curves have no boolean modifier, but you can redo it with few geometry nodes:

[image]

Add a geometry node modifier and create a new node tree.

Add an object info for the cutter object and link it in the input of the node tree. Most likely, set the object info to "relative".

Add a mesh boolean node and link it to the cutter object.

[image]

---

If you have a "normal" curve you can just the "cyclic" checkbox to "cut" it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @lemon: i extended your answer a bit - i hope you don't mind. If yes, just tell me, then i delete that part.

Comment: no pb, @Chris. Thanks